# Oracle PLSQL get difference between 2 datetime fields ignoring days

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql, date-arithmetic

I would like to find the simplest way of calculating the difference **in hours** between 2 dates from Oracle datetime fields whilst **ignoring** the days, months & years portion. For example:

```
Datetime 1 (DATE variable) = 10/05/2017 16:00:00
Datetime 2 (DATE variable) = 15/05/2017 19:34:23

Required result (NUMBER output) = 3.576 hours
```

This is formula will be used in a PLSQL procedure, the output needs to be a number as above. I would imagine some combination of TO_DATE & TRUNC might work. Any help would be most appriciated and apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Is month and year considered?

Comment: What format do you need the result in? Would an interval do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `sssss` date mask to get just the time element as the number of seconds since midnight. Then it's just a matter of simple arithmentic:

```
select (to_number(to_char(datetime2, 'sssss')) 
         - to_number(to_char(datetime1, 'sssss')) / 3600 as diff_hours
from dual;
```

PL/SQL version is the same....

```
declare
    Datetime1 DATE := to_date('10/05/2017 16:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
    Datetime2 DATE := to_date('15/05/2017 19:34:23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
    hours_diff number;
begin
    hours_diff := (to_number(to_char(datetime2, 'sssss')) 
         - to_number(to_char(datetime1, 'sssss'))) / 3600 ;
    dbms_output.put_line(hours_diff);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @APC!